# Getting rows from one table and latest 1 row from an associated table, in LINQ

Tags: linq, select, group-by

This question is similar to this one:

[LINQ to SQL: GroupBy() and Max() to get the object with latest date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704821/linq-to-sql-groupby-and-max-to-get-the-object-with-latest-date)

But I have a table which I want to return a lot of rows from. It's primary key is used as a foreign key in a second table. For each row returned from the first row, I also want to return (in the same result set) the latest (in this case, ordered by a datetime field) 1 row.

How would this be constructed in LINQ using C#?

The best I have is:

```
    var instances = from i in ContextDB.Instances
                    join p in ContextDB.Points on i.InstanceID equals p.InstanceID
                    where categoryIDs.Contains(j.CategoryID)
                    group p by p.InstanceID into latestPoint
                    select new latestPoint.OrderBy(i => i.Instance.Title).FirstOrDefault();
```

But this is clearly wrong.  Although I think I'm understanding `group` correctly I don't think I'm understanding `into` correctly.

[EDIT] To avoid confusion, I think this question can be summed up as "How to do rows from one table along with the latest 1 row for each from another table?"

Comment: You need to clear up your edit.. i think there is a typo.

Comment: There are better ways to do this, and it would start with having associations/relationships in your entity model.  Are there any associations between Instances/CategoryInstances/Points in your model?

Comment: Yes, CategoryInstances -> Instances on InstanceID (in both), Instances -> Point on InstanceID (in both). There are table references in the schema. I shall remove the line involving CategoryInstances from the sample as it will cause confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
var instances = from i in ContextDB.Instances
                where i.CategoryInstances.Any(categoryIDs.Contains(ci => ci.CategoryID))
                select new
                {
                    Instance = i,
                    LatestPoint = i.Points.OrderBy(i => i.Instance.Title).FirstOrDefault()
                };
```

Note that I can remove a lot of redundancy by [using associations instead of join](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2010/01/13/38525/).

Comment: Sometimes I had giving suggestions knowing that they should be doing it a better way... but this is a valid one assuming a link between Instance and points.